# Kubernetes dashboard not working

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to implement the kubernetes dashboard but all the time it is in CrashLoopBackoff status and doesn't matter how many times I deploy it it has the same faith

```
host-xxx:~ # kubectl get pods --all-namespaces                                                                                                                                                                                          
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default       locust-master-pr59t                     1/1       Running            0          2d
default       my-nginx-2565190728-8z0eh               1/1       Running            0          2d
default       my-nginx-2565190728-if4my               1/1       Running            0          2d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-1975554030-80rxv   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   249        21h
```

I have the yaml file from the "kubectl create -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard-head.yaml"

```
host-xxx:~ # kubectl describe pod --namespace=kube-system kubernetes-dashboard-1975554030-80rxv
Name:           kubernetes-dashboard-1975554030-80rxv
Namespace:      kube-system
Node:           host-44-11-1-25/44.11.1.25
Start Time:     Wed, 21 Dec 2016 14:49:48 +0000
Labels:         app=kubernetes-dashboard
                pod-template-hash=1975554030
Status:         Running
IP:             172.20.140.2
Controllers:    ReplicaSet/kubernetes-dashboard-1975554030
Containers:
  kubernetes-dashboard:
    Container ID:               docker://708aac5cebdff057b69cec94e582cb45f7dba424c336fb320dd0d5e3243fc323
    Image:                      gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.5.0
    Image ID:                   docker://sha256:e5133bac8024ac6c916f16df8790259b5504a800766bee87dcf90ec7d634a418
    Port:                       9090/TCP
    State:                      Waiting
      Reason:                   CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:                 Terminated
      Reason:                   Error
      Exit Code:                1
      Started:                  Thu, 22 Dec 2016 11:32:12 +0000
      Finished:                 Thu, 22 Dec 2016 11:32:13 +0000
    Ready:                      False
    Restart Count:              244
    Liveness:                   http-get http://:9090/ delay=30s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment Variables:      <none>
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Initialized   True 
  Ready         False 
  PodScheduled  True 
No volumes.
QoS Tier:       BestEffort
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                            SubobjectPath                           Type            Reason                  Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                            -------------                           --------        ------                  -------
  20h           3m              245     {kubelet host-44-11-1-25}       spec.containers{kubernetes-dashboard}   Normal          Pulling                 pulling image "gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.5.0"
  20h           3m              246     {kubelet host-44-11-1-25}                                               Warning         MissingClusterDNS       kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to DNSDefault policy.
  20h           3m              245     {kubelet host-44-11-1-25}       spec.containers{kubernetes-dashboard}   Normal          Pulled                  Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.5.0"
  20h           3m              236     {kubelet host-44-11-1-25}       spec.containers{kubernetes-dashboard}   Normal          Created                 (events with common reason combined)
  20h           3m              236     {kubelet host-44-11-1-25}       spec.containers{kubernetes-dashboard}   Normal          Started                 (events with common reason combined)
  20h           3s              5940    {kubelet host-44-11-1-25}       spec.containers{kubernetes-dashboard}   Warning         BackOff                 Back-off restarting failed docker container
  20h           3s              5906    {kubelet host-44-11-1-25}                                               Warning         FailedSync              Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "kubernetes-dashboard" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=kubernetes-dashboard pod=kubernetes-dashboard-1975554030-80rxv_kube-system(b893d9c4-c78c-11e6-bd87-fa163e39bb70)"
```

I am nto sure why I have this error message, on the minion it looks like the image is pulled and I can pull it with docker..

Do you guys have a theory on this ?

Answer (score 1):

The image pulled successfully and the container is failing to start in the POD, on this stage you could check it out the problem verifying the logs of the container:

`kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system kubernetes-dashboard-1975554030-80rxv`

The kubelet issued a warning:

> kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to DNSDefault policy.

Maybe the problem is related to DNS, I had a custom installation where the dashboard container only starts when the DNS is active, verify the logs to understand why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the early answer said ,

You could use command `kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system kubernetes-dashboard-1975554030-80rxv` to check error details about what happened.

For errors `kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to DNSDefault policy.`

Maybe you did not enable kubedns component yet, which may cause this problem.

If you are still using `https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard-head.yaml` to create your kubernetes dashboard, you could run command `kubectl edit pod kubernetes-dashboard-1975554030-80rxv -n kube-system` , to manually change DNS policy to default. The key should be `spec.template.spec.dnsPolicy` to `Default` then recreate this Pod to see if it will work .

More details could be found in http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/04/configuring-private-dns-zones-upstream-nameservers-kubernetes.html

BTW , you could also use official dashboard to create https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started